# Elementwise multiplication of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried different solutions refering to this problem but nothing worked.
I have 3 columns of type float and I want to compare the moltiplication of those with another column row by row. Original dataframe looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Result |
+------+------+------+--------+
|  4.5 |  2.0 |  2.0 |   18.0 |
|  2.3 |  1.0 |  3.5 |   8.05 |
|  2.5 |  5.2 |  3.0 |    5.0 |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

Third row is obviously wrong, first and second rows are right.
So I created a new column named Check, which should tell, if column Result is the multiplication of col1,col2 and col3.

```
df['Check'] = np.where((df.col1*df.col2*df.col3) != falseVol.VOLUM,'Result is wrong', 'Result is right')
```

Because I got wrong results with this, I tried several ways to multiply columns and created another column to store the calculated results in:

```
df['calculated'] = df['col1'] * df['col2'] * df['col3']
df['calculated'] = df['col1'].multiply(df['col2'] * df['col3'], axis=0)
```

Each gives me matching results but the check does not work.

How does row by row mulitplication of several columns and comparing work?
Thank you.

Comment: 6.585600e+05 is 658,560

Comment: yes, sorry my mistake. Results were right but not the comparison with the Result column. Changed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.prod`/`np.prod` to multiply your columns (effectively generalising to many columns), and use `np.isclose` to perform elementwise floating comparison with `df.Result`.

```
np.isclose(df.iloc[:, :-1].prod(axis=1), df.Result)
```

Or,

```
np.isclose(np.prod(df.iloc[:, :-1], axis=1), df.Result)
```

```
array([ True,  True, False])
```

Where,

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].prod(axis=1)

0    18.00
1     8.05
2    39.00
dtype: float64
```

Note that performing a direct `eq` comparison yields an incorrect result -

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].prod(axis=1).eq(df.Result)

0     True
1    False   # incorrect
2    False
dtype: bool
```

This is a consequence of [floating point inaccuracies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).